# D3 force directed graph moving text

Tags: d3.js

I'm want to add moving labels on nodes in a D3 force directed graph (example : http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html). I don't have problem to add some text (nodes names defined in my data.json), but is X/Y position is fixed to the initial nodes X/Y position. I try transform and translate functions but without success. Here is a sample of my code :

```
// Update the nodes…
node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
    .style("fill", color);    

node.transition()
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; });

// Labels   
node.enter().append("svg:text")     
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.y; })        
    .attr("fill", "#ffffff")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'center')
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });   

// Enter any new nodes.
node.enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("class", "node")    
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; })
    .style("fill", color)
    .on("click", click)  
    .call(force.drag);      

// Exit any old nodes.
node.exit().remove();   
} 

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; }); 


    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

}
```

Comment: You could group your texts and your circles within `<g>`s. See this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first have to label selection like this

```
text = vis.selectAll("text.label")    
     .data(nodes);

   // Enter any new label
    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  //remove text for collapsed nodes.
  text.exit().remove();
```

Then in the ticks function handle the text move (This is what you were missing as a result of which your text was coming fixed)

```
function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  //this will handle the label move
  text.attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });    
}
```

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/frdc8fxj/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! Strangely graph don't have the same behavior when i use d3.js and d3.v3.min.js.

Comment: it will work well with the minified too...If it addressed your concern then accept it as answer Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that when i click on a circle , a sub-circle's name appear (the first name after the root), not the circle name. Moreover the first circle level is not proportional of his children's values.